# Box2D + Citrus Engine - Proper Pong Paddles

Tags: physics, box2d, flash, starling

I am creating a pong clone for my first Citrus Engine project using Box2D. I've tried two types of paddles, both do not fully work.

1) Paddle is a dynamic body with a restitution of 1.0 and friction of 0.0.

**Problem:** The bouncing ball will move the paddle when it collides.

2) Paddle is a kinematic body type.

**Problem:** The paddle will not detect collision with the walls of the game screen.

**Question:** How can I create a paddle object that will not be affected by the collision of the ball while colliding normally with the game walls?

Comment: Why do you need to use a physics engine for this mechanic? It is somewhat overkill and doesn't suit the functionality a physical simulation provides.

Comment: as a case study, i'd like to know how to implement this kind of mechanic for future designs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying a [Prismatic Joint](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/joints-prismatic) to a Dynamic Body. That should stop the ball from moving your paddle.